# Make Bootstrap tabs active on MVC action

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I want the tab to be set to active once I click on that tab (action). However, the issue I am experiencing is that the "Dashboard" tab is always set to active

```
<div class="row top-buffer">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("Dashboard", "Index")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Users", "Users")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Investigator Groups", "Groups")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Assign Games", "AssignGames")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Reports", "Reports")</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Edit:**
I tried doing the following, which now allows the tabs to be set to active, but no longer redirects to the action.

```
  <li class="active" data-toggle="tab">@Html.ActionLink("Dashboard", "Index")</li>
  <li data-toggle="tab">@Html.ActionLink("Users", "Users")</li>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

follow this tutorial [Setting the active menu item in a MVC C# Bootstrap application](http://chadhaney.me/blog/bootstrap-active-menu) 
by adding an extension method

```
 public static class HtmlHelpers
{
    public static string IsActive(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string action, string controller)
    {
        var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;

        var routeAction = routeData.Values["action"].ToString();
        var routeController = routeData.Values["controller"].ToString();

        var returnActive = (controller == routeController && action == routeAction);

        return returnActive ? "active" : "";
    }
}
```

and then use it

```
 <li class="@Html.IsActive("Index", "Dashboard")">@Html.ActionLink("Dashboard", "Index")</li>
 <li class="@Html.IsActive("Users", "Users")">@Html.ActionLink("Users", "Users")</li>
```